# Include in Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse

I am very new in Android development.

Was just wondering is there any way to include codes in "activity" just like we do in php?

Can we use Layouts from one activity to another activity, without actually writing them.

For eg.
In php we can include `<?php include("page.php");?>`

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: I tried to answer this question, but it's too basic. Asking this, there's too much you don't know. You should start with a tutorial, or getting started article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes, there is an include statement, but only works on xml layout.

below you can find one example of it. the real purpose of this include is to use it like a template

```
<include
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/activity_header_template" />
```

and if your question is related to the java source code, there is also an import option but that is not like c++, or php methods where you write some piece of code and attach the include file where ever you want. if you want some thing like that it should be a library

**For Instance,**

import ActionBarSherlock Library into your project. Go to your project properties by right clicking on your project > Properties > Android > Add > Select ActionBarSherlockLib > Apply > OK.

and then inside your main activity class

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity; // this is how you import the just a library
```

Answer (score 1):

It is all automatically included.

You are perhaps thinking of import statements.  The Activities you write in the same package will automatically be included.  For other code, you can just press [Ctrl/Command][Shift][O] in Eclipse to auto-import.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to include codes in "activity"

If by "codes in activity" you mean "XML layout files", then, yes, [there is an `<include>` tag that you can use](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

If by "codes in activity" you mean Java code, then that is not possible, as Java does not support an `include` directive the way C/C++ do.